# vhost config for Zend Framework 2 in Xampp (windows)

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2, vhosts

I have installed zend framework 2 in xamp (Windows) & its accessible when i call `http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/`. I am trying to set virtual host using the below config using `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
     DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

and have configured `127.0.0.1  zf2-tutorial.localhost` in host file. but when i call `zf2-tutorial.localhost` in browser, all i get is `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/xampp/`. I also tried adding this in `httpd.conf`, still the result is same. Please Help ?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since editing vhosts?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted Apache as well full system reboot

Comment: try to adding a row on file hosts di windows: 127.0.0.1 zf2-tutorial.localhost the file hosts il located on C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Yes, i have made that entry in my host file too ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong, i never added vhost for local host. Once, i configured the localhost in httpd-vhost.cong like this, it worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you configure the virtual host in the file `httpd-vhost.com` make sure that the virtual host include file is uncommented in httpd.conf file, i.e. remove the # from the beginning of the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: i have checked all that. it was included. but still no success so i reinstalled Xampp & now everything works

Answer (score 0):

I personally dont like the xammp software and rather set up my own apache but there shouldn't be to many differences in setting up a project. I also like having alias's for my project's rather then accessing them trough "localhost" or a "ip". My config usually looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tutorial.local
    ServerAlias tutorial.local
    DocumentRoot c:/Apache24/htdocs/tutorial/public/
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory c:/Apache24/htdocs/tutorial/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After setting up the Virtual Host with the aliases you'll have to open your hosts file within `FILESYSTEM:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\` and add a host.

```
localhost or IP  tutorial.local
```

keep in mind that you'll have to open this file as a administrator and may disable your Antivirus/Spyblocker.

Comment: Thx for your help, but still it didnt sort the issue. I corrected the server name, alias, Document root and directory, still it is having the same issue...

Comment: Yes.  I made a entry in the host file